# can I replace "data" with "pieces on information"

Tags: meaning

"Pieces of information are transmitted across the Internet in packets of limited size called datagrams."

Comment: You can.  You do have a count mismatch between "packets" and (sic) "datagramm".

Comment: But why not just replace it with *information*:  "Information is transmitted across the Internet in packets of limited size called datagrams."

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the plural is hardly ever used. A "piece of information" focusses on the particularity and importance of that information.

"And that piece of information, Holmes, cast an entirely new light on the case."

The construction "piece of information" is usually used when the similar "piece of a puzzle" is implied.

Where more than one piece of information is referred to, it's usually just called "information".

Certainly, most computer usages would not use the term.

"This protocol allows the transmission of pieces of information at a rate of 100 million bits per second," is clearly not normal or even desirable usage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, although I would replace "pieces" with "segments" in that sentence - it also refers to a subsection of a whole but implies a more deliberate delineation between each piece/segment.